# How to show images in a TDBGrid using the image location from a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, c++builder, dbgrid

I am creating a data saving software using C++ Builder.

I have placed a `TDBGrid` on my Form, where I show information from my MySQL database.

There is an image column in my grid where I want to show images. I can only see the image location in the column. How can I show the image using the image location?

Comment: may be load into bitmap and render on the custom OnPaint event of the `DBGrid`? never did such thing for `DBGrid` but with `TListBox,TComboBox` and `TStringGrid` I did do custom gfx so the `DBGrid` should not be any different. You just need to set the DBGrid so it fires the OnPaint method for each cell ... The only problem I see with this is to manage the images itself so the app is not crawling because of it ... btw the image can be loaded directly from database using memory streams (they do not need to be on local HDD)... Take in mind I am stuck with BDS2006 VCL and newer versions can differ

Comment: Use the [`TDBGrid::OnDrawColumnCell`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TCustomDBGrid.OnDrawColumnCell) event, not the `OnPaint` event. The event will provide a [`TColumn`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TColumn) parameter, which has a [`Field`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TColumn.Field) property to access the particular [`TField`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Data.DB.TField) that is being drawn. You can read the image data from the field and draw it onto the grid's `Canvas` however you want.